# Mulitple panel-body in a panel div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it ok to have mulitple `panel-body` in a `panel` div? Or will there be any side effect.

For example:

```
<div class="panel panel-default special-style-border">
    <div class="panel-heading">
         <div class="panel-title">Heading 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
     Body One
   </div>

   <hr />

    <div class="panel-heading">
       <div class="panel-title">Heading 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
     Body Two
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's just a CSS class, there is no technical issue with having multiple instances (in fact, that's what classes are for) - did you try it?

Comment: CSS style classes can be used freely. However element ids should be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS class tags are intended to be used when the properties will apply to multiple elements.

ID tags on the other hand are intended to be used once on a single element.

ID's are given higher precedence than classes so if you manage to give some element an ID tag with the same name as a class...the properties of the ID tag will be used.